# Freemarker - Rendering tree type model from java Object

Tags: spring, object, model, freemarker

Hi all 
I am new to Freemarker so not much aware of its API.

I have a requirement to render outline -tree of an object.
My platform is Spring mvc and Freemarker.
On controller side, i have a object bean that contains data in for of a tree.
I need to pass this to some free marker templates and create a page that represents object model.
Objetc model has information - on what elements are in object .
Please suggest how and using what technology i can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC provides support for FreeMarker *views* that allow you to use FreeMarker templates as you would JSPs. See [Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/freemarker/FreeMarkerView.html).

As for the outline tree, you can simply pass it into the *model* (which is typically a map) by giving it a name. It becomes a FreeMarker *variable* and you can access it and all its properties in your template.